# Data not showing in listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show data to listview but it doesn't show anything.there is json below ,am i doing something wrong,i tired to print the data in api call but i can print the data but not in the listview,
i having hardtime to understand what i doing wrong or correct.please help me on this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        if (status == true) {

          var company_list = value['doc'];
          for (int i = 0; i < company_list.length; i++) {
            print(company_list);
            var mobile_list = company_list["mobile"];
            var email_list = company_list["email"];
            company_model.add(CompanyModel.fromJson(data,mobile_list,email_list));
          }
          setState(() {
            print("UI Updated");
          });
        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
```

Json

```
{
    "status":true,
    "doc":{
        "mobile":[
            "9961256754",
            "8974525672"
        ],
        "email":[

        ],
        "_id":"5f3a0dfe88b9d50453e92133",
        "name":"MRC Labour",
        "terms":{
            "english":"We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the 
         labourers",
            "malayalam":"We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the 
         labourers"
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class CompanyModel {
  String id = "";
  String mobile = "";
  String email = "";
  String name = "";
  String english = "";
  String malayalam = "";

  CompanyModel({this.id, this.mobile, this.email, this.name, this.english,this.malayalam});

  CompanyModel.fromJson(json,mobile_list,email_list)
      : id = json['_id'].toString(),
        mobile = mobile_list,
        email = email_list,
        name = json['name'].toString(),
        english = json['terms']['english'].toString(),
        malayalam = json['terms']['malayalam'].toString();
}
```

[image: Data i am geting,]

When the debugger hit at this line it breaks without any errors `company_model.add(CompanyModel.fromJson(data,mobile_list,email_list));`

Comment: where you define and using  ompany_model?

Comment: `List<CompanyModel> company_model = [];` l@DeepakRor

Answer (score 0):

Hi your Models Should be Like this

```
class CompanyModel {
    Doc doc;
    bool status;

    CompanyModel({this.doc, this.status});

    factory CompanyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return CompanyModel(
            doc: json['doc'] != null ? Doc.fromJson(json['doc']) : null, 
            status: json['status'], 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['status'] = this.status;
        if (this.doc != null) {
            data['doc'] = this.doc.toJson();
        }
        return data;
    }
}

class Doc {
    String id;
    List<String> email;
    List<String> mobile;
    String name;
    Terms terms;

    Doc({this.id, this.email, this.mobile, this.name, this.terms});

    factory Doc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Doc(
            id: json['_id'], 
            email: json['email'] != null ? new List<String>.from(json['email']) : null, 
            mobile: json['mobile'] != null ? new List<String>.from(json['mobile']) : null, 
            name: json['name'], 
            terms: json['terms'] != null ? Terms.fromJson(json['terms']) : null, 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['_id'] = this.id;
        data['name'] = this.name;
        if (this.email != null) {
            data['email'] = this.email;
        }
        if (this.mobile != null) {
            data['mobile'] = this.mobile;
        }
        if (this.terms != null) {
            data['terms'] = this.terms.toJson();
        }
        return data;
    }
}

class Terms {
    String english;
    String malayalam;

    Terms({this.english, this.malayalam});

    factory Terms.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Terms(
            english: json['english'], 
            malayalam: json['malayalam'], 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['english'] = this.english;
        data['malayalam'] = this.malayalam;
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Use Like**

```
CompanyModel model = CompanyModel.fromJson(value);
```

Comment: This is converted with json to dart right but. can you do that with my code.we have following code format like above question.@Deepak Ror

Comment: just print your exception. then I can solve your problem as you want.

Comment: There is no exception,`var company_list = value['doc'];` upto this line i have the data,i think problem is looping the data @Deepak Ror

Comment: i have updated with debugger with image check it out@Deepak Ror

Answer (score 0):

As per the questioner request posting my old code for reference.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:igloled_app/components/urls.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';


class Category with ChangeNotifier{

  var logger = Logger(
    printer: PrettyPrinter(),
  );

  List<SetCategory> allCategoryList = [];

  int get getlength{
      return allCategoryList.length;
  }

  bool get getAllCatisempty
  {
    return allCategoryList.isEmpty;
  }

  int get initialCatId{
    if(allCategoryList.isNotEmpty)
    {
      return allCategoryList[0].catId;
    }
    else
      {
        return 25504210;
      }

  }


Future<List<SetCategory>>  getAllCategories() async {


    try
    {
      Response allCategory = await FetchData().fetchCategoryData();

//      print('getAllCategories status ${allCategory.statusCode}');


      if (allCategory.statusCode == 200) {
        var categoryData = allCategory.body;
        int totalcount = jsonDecode(categoryData)['count'];

        if (allCategoryList.length != totalcount) {
          allCategoryList.clear();

          for (int i = 0; i < totalcount; i++) {
//            print(jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['id']);
//            print(jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['name']);

            allCategoryList.add(SetCategory(
              catId: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['id'],
              catName: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['name'],
              catThumbnail: jsonDecode(categoryData)['items'][i]['thumbnailUrl'],
            ));

          }

          notifyListeners();

          return allCategoryList;
        }
      }
      else
        {
          notifyListeners();


          return allCategoryList;

        }
//      print('allcategorylist length ${allCategoryList.length}');


    }
    catch(e){


      logger.e(e);


    }

    notifyListeners();
    return allCategoryList;


}



}

class SetCategory {

  int catId;
  String catName;
  String catThumbnail;

  SetCategory(
      { this.catId, this.catName, this.catThumbnail});

}
```

Comment: no this is't working @Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: can you tell me what is showing when you print(jsonDecode(jsonData)['doc']);

Comment: `{mobile: [9961256754, 8974525672], email: [], _id: 5f3a0dfe88b9d50453e92133, name: MRC Labour, terms: {english: We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the labourers, malayalam: നിങ്ങളും തൊഴിലാളികളും തമ്മിലുള്ള പ്രശ്നങ്ങൾക്ക് ആപ് ഉടമകളോ ആപ് നിർമാതാക്കളോ ഉത്തരവാദിയായിരിക്കുന്നതല്ല}}` @Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: Now the list is printing right? to access mobile value use `print(jsonDecode(jsonData)['doc'][0]['mobile']); `

Comment: i have no problem accessing the data,in my code `var mobile_list = company_list["mobile"];` i have this data,i think problem is with in  model @Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: i have updated with debugger with image check it out@Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: any idea@Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: No idea bro. Actually i tried flutter 4 moths ago to develop an app, Now don't have much idea, I created a product catalog app.  If you want I can paste the code i used to list the category. I didn't use this model method.

Comment: hmm,give me the code, i will look into it,may be it helps @Alvin John Niravukalayil

Comment: I had edited the above answer

Comment: @MorbiusBlack Did you solve it?